# reading xml from php to c#

Tags: c#, xml

Hello can somebody please show me how to make reading this xml in c# work properly, I've tried alot and i can't get it to work, Help is very much appreciated!

I create this xml in php:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <root>
  <budget>n/A</budget> 
  <cast>Robert De Niro / Katherine Heigl / Diane Keaton / Amanda Seyfried / Topher Grace / Susan Sarandon / Robin Williams / Ben Barnes / Christine Ebersole / David Rasche / Patricia Rae / Ana Ayora / Kyle Bornheimer / Megan Ketch / Christa Campbell</cast> 
  <country>USA</country> 
  <directors>Justin Zackham</directors> 
  <genres>Comedy</genres> 
  <languages>English / Spanish</languages> 
  <discription>A long-divorced couple fakes being married as their family unites for a wedding.</discription> 
  <plot>A long-divorced couple fakes being married as their family unites for a wedding.</plot> 
  <trailer>http://www.imdb.com/video/imdb/vi2079761945/player</trailer> 
  <poster>posters/1931435.jpg</poster> 
  <rating>5.2</rating> 
  <releasedate>26 April 2013 (USA)</releasedate> 
  <runtime>89 min</runtime> 
  <title>It's never too late to start acting like a family.</title> 
  <tagline>It's never too late to start acting like a family.</tagline> 
  <year>2013</year> 
  <votes>1,466</votes> 
  <url>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1931435/</url> 
  <sites><a href="http://facebook.com/TheBigWeddingMovie" target="_blank">Official Facebook</a> / <a href="http://thebigweddingmovie.com/" target="_blank">Official site</a></sites> 
  </root>
```

I'm trying to parse it in c# like this:

```
                        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("data.xml"))
                        {
                            reader.ReadStartElement("root");
                            while (reader.Name == "title")
                            {
                                XElement el = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(reader);
                            }

                            reader.ReadEndElement();
                        }
```

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong here?

I get no title in my results.

whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your xml is flat, how about using Linq and loading it to a dictionary

```
var response = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://citfree.com/cronjobs/imdb/fetch.php?url=Star+Wars");

var dict = XDocument.Parse(response.Trim()).Root
            .Elements()
            .ToDictionary(e => e.Name.LocalName, e => (string)e);

Console.WriteLine(dict["budget"]);
```

PS: To read directly from file you can use `XDocument.Load(filename)`

Comment: i tried this but got web exception


                var response = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.citfree.com/cronjobs/imdb/fetch.php?url=" + IMDB);
                var doc = XDocument.Parse(response).Root.Elements();                
                var dict = doc.ToDictionary(e => e.Name.LocalName, e => (string)e);

                Console.WriteLine(dict["budget"]);

Comment: @Dean See the updated answer. I added a `Trim`, since your site prepends a blank line into the xml.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to have an object in C# that holds the XML representation?

Try this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
```

Comment: im getting exception using this too.

Comment: Can you update your question and provide your current source code?